# Call Java code from java script

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, taglib

I have my custom tag in a jsp file. This custom tag injects some java scripts functions in my jsp at runtime. but for injecting this java script, the custom tag also needs an attribute value from request object. This attribute is set in request by a Java code before the jsp loads.

My problem is I don't want to inject the java script (which my custom tag injects) at the page load time. I want it to be injected on a checkbox check. As I mentioned earlier, My custom tag also need a request attribute. I want this request attribute to set after the checkbox is checked but before the custom tag injects the java script in jsp page.

Thanks

Comment: are you using an MVC framework like Struts or something?

Answer (score 0):

As javascript is a client side script, it cannot invoke java methods directly which resides on the server

Without any particular java frameworks, you could make use of Java Server Pages (JSP) to invoke deleteconfig.initiate() when it receives a GET request from javascript.

**sending request**

```
//javascript code
function callInititiate(){

   //This sends a get request to executeInit.jsp
   //
   $.get('localhost/myWebbApp/executeInit.jsp');

}

$(callInitiate);
```

**Receive Request**

On the server side, you should have executeInit.jsp that calls deleteconfig.initiate() static method

```
//in executeInit.jsp
<%@ page import="deleteconfig"%>

<%
// executes initiate() static method
deleteconfig.initiate();

%>
```

Perhaps reading more about Java Server Pages can get you started!